# CPLEX: Indexing an array using the assigned value of a dvar

Tags: cplex

I want to reference to an array using the value that is assigned to a dvar. However, an error message was given by CPLEX instead - "CP cannot extract expression". What can I do to overcome the error?

Below is the codes for my problem - a jobs assignment based on the available time of the employees.

```
using CP;

{string} Employee = ...;

{string} Jobs = ...;

range EmpIDs = 0..card(Employee)-1;

{int} AvailSlot[EmpIDs] = ...;

range Slots = 1...10

dvar int Time[Jobs] in Slots;

dvar int Emp[Jobs] in EmpIDs;

subject to{

forall (x in Jobs) {
   Time[x] in AvailSlot[Emp[x]];}  //this constraints the assigned time slot for the job x to be one of the available time slots of the employee that is assigned with the same job x. 

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

using CP;

```
{string} Employee = {"A","B"};

{string} Jobs = {"K","L"};

range EmpIDs = 0..card(Employee)-1;

{int} AvailSlot[EmpIDs] = [{1,2},{2,3}];


range Slots = 1..10;


dvar int Time[Jobs] in Slots;

dvar int Emp[Jobs] in EmpIDs;

subject to{


forall (x in Jobs) {
   //Time[x] in AvailSlot[Emp[x]];  
   or (j in EmpIDs) (j==Emp[x] && Time[x] in AvailSlot[j]);
}
}

assert forall (x in Jobs) 
   Time[x] in AvailSlot[Emp[x]];
```

works fine